# Product Images not shown after uploading in Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7

I am having a very strange problem, i am uploading product images through admin panel but when i upload image it shows 100% uploaded but doesn't show image row at all .
Even i import product or upload image via FTP then still same issue Tried so many things but couldn't make it work.

[image]

Please help if anybody know about this problem

Comment: Set permissions of the `media` folder recursively to `777`.

Comment: Thanks Simon, for quick response  But Permission is already 777 for media folder.                                         What may be issue. please reply Thanks

Comment: Simon have you another solution, please help                Thanks

Comment: Was it working before and stop working? Is this a new installation? Can you upload other images (eg category)?

Comment: How big are the files you are trying to upload?

Comment: I think Flash player problem. Plz... install latest version of Flash Player and refresh your page.

Comment: I had this problem when trying to upload images using Mozilla Firefox. I switched to Google Chrome and can upload images there with no problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Possible reason 2**: Media folder is owned by another user. It can happen if you transfer your Magento store from one server to another.

Solution: Change ownership of the /media/ folder:

> chown -R {username}:{username} media/

Important: Make sure that folder owner is the same user as your web server user. If you are not sure, contact your server support administrator.

**Possible reason 3**: Magento cannot resize images due low PHP memory limit. Magento resize images using GD library, however if there is no sufficient amount of memory for such operation Magento will return a placeholder image.

**Solution**: Increase your memory limit. You should open your .htaccess file and find this string:

php_value memory_limit 256M

Make sure that this value is at least 256M, 512M is better.

**Possible reason 4**: The GD library is not installed/configured.

**Solution**: Make sure that your hosting installed GD library on your server, you can check it using php info.

**Possible reason 5**: Wrong attribute scope for small_image, thumbnail, base_image. Sometimes Magento processes images incorrectly, if they have scope=Store View (especially in case of multi-store installation).

**Solution**: You should open your Magento admin panel -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage attributes. After this you should find image, small_image & thumbnail attributes. Make sure that all these attributes have scope = Global.

**Possible reason 6**: Problem with safe mode.

**Solution**: It is not recommended to disable safe mode, but if you tried all other solutions you might try to disable safe mode on your server.

Read more [BUGFIXES:PRODUCT IMAGES NOT SHOWING IN MAGENTO](http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-images-not-showing/)